# How to retrieve all primary keys of a table using hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I need to retrieve all primary keys of a table and put them in a list.
Any method that I have found so far let me retrieve each record as an object, which force me to retrieve their primary keys separately and add them to the list.

Is there any other approach to retrieve the primary keys of a table and adding them to a list?

Using the following code hibernate returns objects but I need it to return a list of primary keys to store them in pk list.

```
            List pk = new ArrayList():
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyTable.class, "mytable");
            pk = criteria.list();
```

if mytable is as following

```
id name value
1  a      z4
2  f      o2
```

pk list should be

```
[1,2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply create an HQL query that returns the field you want:

```
session.createQuery("SELECT mt.id FROM MyTable mt").list();
```

assuming your primary key field is named `id` and `MyTable` is your entity. You can also do it with `Criteria` and `Projections`.

Answer (score 4):

There are generally there ways to achieve that 
1) Using Criteria API
2) Using HQL
3) Using Native Query

From the above hibernate queries way , better to us (1) and (2) , the 3rd way has dependency on the type of database.

1) Using Criteria API

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyTable.class, "mytable");
criteria.setProjection( Projections.projectionList().add( Projections.property("mytable.id"), "mytable.id"));

List<Long> ids=criteria.list();
```

2) Using HQL

Solution is already explained by `Sotirious`

3) Using Native Query

```
session.createSQLQuery(" SELECT mytable.id FROM MyTable mytable ").addScalar("ID","Hibernate.LONG").list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use finder queries directly on repository(Spring JpaRepository) methods.

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTable, KeyType> {

    @Query("select mt.id from MyTable mt")
    List<KeyType> getAllIds();
}
```